# Why is a reference variable accessed via auto-deref moved?

Tags: rust

I thought I got the idea of move semantics until this code.

```
fn main() {
    let v = Data {
        body: vec![10, 40, 30],
    };
    p(&v);
}

fn p(d: &Data) {
    for i in d.body {
        // &d.body, Why d.body move?
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

struct Data {
    body: Vec<i32>,
}
```

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:9:14
  |
9 |     for i in d.body {
  |              ^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `d.body` which is behind a `&` reference
 --> src/main.rs:9:14
  |
8 | fn p(d: &Data) {
  |         ----- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut Data`
9 |     for i in d.body {
  |              ^^^^^^
  |              |
  |              cannot move out of `d.body` which is behind a `&` reference
  |              `d` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be moved
```

I passed a reference, and I accessed a field via auto-deref feature, so why is it a move?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is field accessing on pointer.

Check [Field Access Expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/field-expr.html) :

> if the type of the expression to the left of the dot is a pointer, it
>   is automatically dereferenced as many times as necessary to make the
>   field access possible

Sample for how Rust evaluates Field Access Expression on Borrowed Content :

```
let d = Data { /*input*/}
let body = (&d).body // -> (*&d).body -> d.body
let ref_body = &(&d).body // -> &(*&).body -> &d.body -> &(d.body)
```

Note : d is still borrowed content, auto deref is just needed to access the fields.

---

### Why move ?

Consider this code:

```
struct Data {
    body: Vec<i32>,
    id: i32,
}

fn p(mut d: &Data) {
    let id = d.id;
}
```

This code will work as expected and there will be no moves in here so you will able to reuse `d.id`. In this situation:

1. Rust will try to copy the value of `d.id`. Since `d.id` is `i32` and implements the `Copy` trait, it will copy the value to `id`.

Consider this code:

```
fn p(mut d: &Data) {
    let id = d.id; // works
    let body = d.body; // fails
}
```

This code will not work because:

1. Rust will try to copy `d.body` but `Vec<i32>` has no implementation of the `Copy` trait.
2. Rust will try to move `body` from `d`, and you will get the "cannot move out of borrowed content" error.

### How does this effect the loop?

From [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/loop-expr.html#iterator-loops)

> A `for` expression is a syntactic construct for looping over elements provided by an implementation of `std::iter::IntoIterator`
>
> A for loop is equivalent to the following block expression.
>
> ```
> 'label: for PATTERN in iter_expr {
>     /* loop body */
> }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> {
>     let result = match IntoIterator::into_iter(iter_expr) {
>         mut iter => 'label: loop {
>             let mut next;
>             match Iterator::next(&mut iter) {
>                 Option::Some(val) => next = val,
>                 Option::None => break,
>             };
>             let PAT = next;
>             let () = { /* loop body */ };
>         },
>     };
>     result
> }
> ```

This means your vector must have an implementation of `IntoIterator` because `IntoIterator::into_iter(self)` expects `self` as an argument. Luckily, both  [`impl IntoIterator for Vec<T>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b7da2c6e12a6b2a2343e2f1e66fe4f6a1ad55463/src/liballoc/vec.rs#L1705), another is [`impl<'a, T> IntoIterator for &'a Vec<T>`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/b7da2c6e12a6b2a2343e2f1e66fe4f6a1ad55463/src/liballoc/vec.rs#L1746) exist.

### Why does this happen?

Simply:

- When you use `&d.body`, your loop uses the `&Vec` implementation of `IntoIterator`.

This implementation returns an iterator which points at your vector's slice. This means you will get the **reference of elements** from your vector.

- When you use `d.body`, your loop uses the `Vec` implementation of `IntoIterator`.

This implementation returns an iterator which is a consuming iterator. This means your loop will have the **ownership of actual elements**, not their references. For the consuming part this implementation needs the actual vector not the reference, so the move occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the field `body` in `d`. `body` itself is a `Vec<i32>` which is not a reference. If you would use `d` directly, no `&` would be necessary, but since you are accessing a field in `d`, you must specify that you want to have the reference to the field.

Basically `d` owns `body`. If you borrow `d` you cannot steal `body`, it belongs to `d` but you can borrow it.

Comment: *If you would use `d` directly, no `&` would be necessary, but since you are accessing a field in `d`, you must specify that you want to have the reference to the field.* — This answer does not describe why this happens.

Answer (score -1):

This loop will be [desugared into something similar to the following](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#for-loops-and-intoiterator):

```
let mut iter = IntoIterator::into_iter(v);
loop {
    match iter.next() {
        Some(x) => {
            // loop body
        },
        None => break,
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's using `into_iter`, which moves the vector `d.body`.

Comment: This does not address why `d.body` is moved when `d` is a reference.